# select departments where all employees are clerks only

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select only those deps where all employees are clerks.

```
dep   employee_name  designation
10    John           clerk
10    Mark           clerk
10    Mary           manager
20    Livia          clerk
20    Peter          clerk
30    Julia          manager
30    Martin         assistent
30    Viola          assistent
```

so the output will be department 20 because all employees are clerks.

I found one solution ,correct me if there could be a trap

```
   select a.* from table a
    join
            (select dep from table
            group by dep
            having sum(case when designation = 'clerk' then 1 else 0 end)>0 and
            sum (case when designation <> 'clerk' then 1 else 0 end)=0 ) b on a.dep=b.dep;
```

Comment: You must've tried something and that attempt should be in the question.

Comment: Hint: when the min and the max both are 'clerk' ...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
select dp
from employees
group by designation
having min(job) = 'clerk'
   and min(job) = max(job);
```